# I have a method to return all real values of a Quadratic formula. Why do I get a compatible conversion error from String to Double?

Tags: java, return

I am working on a Java program and I am encountering a strange error with my method in Java.

Here is what the block of code looks like:

```
public class Quadratic
{
    private double a = 0;
    private double b = 0;
    private double c = 0;
    private double d =(b*b)-(4*a*c);
    
            public double QuadraticFormReturner(){
                if (d < 0){
                    System.out.println("There are no real solutions for your inputs");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Your X Value is: " + d);

                }
            } // I experience a bug on this line. "missing return statement"

        public Quadratic(double Number1, double Number2, double Number3, double Number4)
            {
                a = Number1;
                b = Number2;
                c = Number3;

    }
}
```

When I noticed the bug, I added a return statement to return `"Your X Value is: "` and then print the value `d`. The strange thing is when I do that, I get this error: `"incompatible types, cannot be converted from string to double"`

This has me confused, I am not returning a double value but a string when a condition is met. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've declared your `QuadraticFormReturner` method as returning a `double`, so it has to return a `double`.

Comment: @tgdavies Thank you! Here is one problem, how do I return the string and double?

Comment: If you want to return both, create a new class which has two fields, a String and a double, and return a new instance of that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic syntax problem, you need to change the method to return **void** if you want to display the println, like this :

```
public void QuadraticFormReturner(){
    d =(b*b)-(4*a*c);
    if (d < 0){
        System.out.println("There are no real solutions for your inputs");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Your X Value is: " + d);

    }
}
```

And you need to put the d equation inside the method, so that this process can only run when the method is being called.